# Stop executing code until my async/await HttpClient get operation finishes executing code (including html calls)

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await

I need to execute `HttpClient` get request synchronously so I found a solution on internet to use `toPromise` instead of subscribe and then await.
However I have noticed that the `this.form =  = this.formBuilder.group` line of code executes before `myAccount` is initialized by the `async` call.
In other words I was expecting that the execution code will block until `this.myAccount` is initialized and then starts executing  `this.form = this.formBuilder.group` line.
Am I understanding async/await in javascript correct. What do I need to do to achieve what I want - that is, wait with execution until `this.myAccount` is initialized by the call `await this.accountService.getById(this.id).toPromise()`.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getByIdSynchronously();

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      scheduledDate: ['', Validators.required],
      required: [''],
      userAvailability: [''],
    });
}
async getByIdSynchronously()
  {
    this.myAccount = await this.accountService.getById(this.id).toPromise();
  }
```

I also have an html page with the first line of code looking like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" *ngIf="!isAdmin">
...
</form >
```

where isAdmin is a local function:

```
get isAdmin()
  {
    if(this.myAccount)
    {
      return this.myAccount.role == Role.Admin;
    }
    else{
      return true;
    }
  }
```

which executes dozen of time before my async/await method finishes so I have to return some artificial true value until my `this.myAccount` is initialized.

**Note**

I have found solution to the first problem - just use `then` operator of the Promise. I can't find the solution for the second problem - to stop `isAdmin` being called from template html until `this.myAccount` is initialized. Is there a remedy for that?

Comment: You can just create another flag and use it to store information about the loaded state. Then your ngIf becomes `*ngIf="isLoaded && !isAdmin"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Promises you should use Observables as Angular also encourages the use of Observables.
The HTTPClient returns an observable so you can subscribe to it instead.

*AccountService*

```js
    getById(id: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get(`URL goes here. ID goes into PARAMS`);
    }
```

Then in your component subscribe to your API call. You can use another variable to stop isAdmin from being called continuously.

```js
isLoaded: boolean = false;
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.accountService.getById(this.id).subscribe(resp=>{
          this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
          scheduledDate: ['', Validators.required],
          required: [''],
          userAvailability: [''] });
          this.isLoaded = true;
      });
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" *ngIf="isLoaded && !isAdmin">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's normal beacause your promise is not resolved : You have to await for your call to getByIdSynchronously (making your ngOninit async as well):

```
async ngOnInit(): void {
await this.getByIdSynchronously();

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  scheduledDate: ['', Validators.required],
  required: [''],
  userAvailability: [''],
}); }
```